# Lines are showing in Safari when using border-radius

Tags: css, safari, border-radius

When using Safari (I'm on 14.0 but it shows up on other versions) and `border-radius`, I get these lines as show in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot with lines]

If I remove `border-radius`, the lines go away.

```html
<div class="modal">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <p>some stuff</p>
</div>
```

```css
body {  
  background-color: green;
}

.modal {
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Here is a JSBin to see it in action: https://jsbin.com/todumosoye/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I don't get those lines in Safari 14 on macOS 10.15.6

Comment: I can confirm it happens for me too. Safari 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610) macOS 10.15.7

Comment: Confirming on Safari 14.0.1 on macOS 10.15.7